# calling wrapper script in subprocess

Tags: python, linux, shell, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a `wrapperexec`, which should call `exec` and a few arguments.

```
subprocess.check_call( ["wrapperexec", "exec", "arg1"], shell=True, cwd="/dirA" )
```

When I call above script it passes no arguments to `wrapperexec`.
But when I change to:

```
subprocess.check_call( ["wrapperexec", "exec", "arg1"], shell=False, cwd="/dirA" )
```

it does pass arguments as expected.
Could someone explain to me, why the former does not work?

EDIT:

Sorry, I was on the complete wrong track when creating this issue. Updated now to the real issue.

Comment: check_call will raise an exception if it can't find the script or if the script returns nonzero. The "end" output suggests that your child program successfully executes but outputs nothing.

Comment: @monk that is what lead me to believe it was the search PATH, but it is actually the command invocation

Answer (score 1):

The environmental `path` is a complicated concept, there is the "base" `path` shared by everything, but you can also temporarily modify or append the `path` in specific processes. This means that if you modify the `path` in your script, but then call a `subprocess`, the `subprocess` will not have the same `path` as the parent script.

Unless you do the following:

```
subprocess.check_call(["nonsystemexec"], shell=True, cwd="/dirA", env=os.environ)
```

Here you are telling the `subprocess` to use your current env, which will include your current `path`.

---

Note: If you wanted to have the `subprocess` use a modified env, but not the same one you have. You can do something like this:

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PATH'] += ';/dirB'
subprocess.check_call(["nonsystemexec"], shell=True, cwd="/dirA", env=env)
```

Comment: This seems to contradict _If env is not None, it must be a mapping that defines the environment variables for the new process; these are used instead of inheriting the current process’ environment, which is the default behavior._ in the docs.

Comment: @LCIDFire Perhaps it may *seem* to do so, but if you will try it, it will work.

Comment: And passing `env` for every check_call, does not make any difference.

Comment: I noticed, that you mentiond `/dirB` but use `/dirA` in your code, also, your `cmd` is a `str` instead of a `list` ?

Comment: `/dirB` is where the file is located, `/dirA` is the `cwd`. `cmd` is actually a `list` but should not make any difference, AFAIK.

Comment: sorry, the environment gets passed on, like the documentation says.